# Issues while setting up passwordless sftp

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp, openssh

I was trying to set up a passwordless sftp from one Red Hat Linux server to another. As "oracle" user, I created the key-pair on server1, copied the publickey over to server2, and then added them to authorized_keys of "oracle" user.

Now from Server1 here's the verbose attempt. Interesting thing to note is the same key pair works alright with another server3. Any suggestions?

```
bash-3.2$ id
uid=108(oracle) gid=51769(dba) groups=51769(dba)

bash-3.2$ sftp -vvv oracle@112.121.13.124
Connecting to 112.121.13.124...
OpenSSH_4.3p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 112.121.13.124 [112.121.13.124] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: loaded 2 keys
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_init: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 133/256
debug2: bits set: 502/1024
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: filename /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 3
debug1: Host '112.121.13.124' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/oracle/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug2: bits set: 534/1024
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa (0x2ba7be62ac90)
debug3: input_userauth_banner



debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup gssapi-with-mic
debug3: remaining preferred: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug3: Trying to reverse map address 112.121.13.124.
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
Unknown code krb5 195

debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Offering public key: /home/oracle/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-dss blen 433
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: SHA1 fp 0e:23:0d:d8:28:27:9e:2e:6c:e5:66:38:4d:c2:0a:ec:8e:9e:5d:1a
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t3 r-1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 4/5 cfd -1)

debug3: channel 0: close_fds r 4 w 5 e 6 c -1
debug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Read from remote host 112.121.13.124: Connection reset by peer
debug1: Transferred: stdin 0, stdout 0, stderr 64 bytes in 0.1 seconds
debug1: Bytes per second: stdin 0.0, stdout 0.0, stderr 811.5
debug1: Exit status -1
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the public/private keys are set up correctly. Try setting it up again, from the first step. If it still isn't working, then show the commands used and their output.

First, clean up on server1 and server2:

```
server1$ mv -i ~/.ssh ~/.ssh.old
server2$ mv -i ~/.ssh ~/.ssh.old
```

Set up the keys:

```
server1$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
...etc
server1$ ssh-copy-id user@server2
...etc
```

Then login/scp/etc:

```
server1$ ssh user@server2
```